# How to close the card by itself after executed a HTTP request?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I have an app with contextual commands. After triggered a contextual command, it will make a HTTP request with a link and post the result on the card, something like, "Completed!". I want this card to be closed by itself after one second so that the user need not to tap to close it. Once the result card is closed, it will go back to contextual command lists with "Ok, glass" at footer and ready for next command.

May i know how to do that?

```
 private class HTTPRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
   try {
    if (mWhat.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {
        // get json via YouTube API
        URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
        mUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)
        url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
        mUrlConnection.getInputStream());
        int ch;
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
        b.append((char) ch);
        }
    mResult = new String(b);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}
return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
mTvInfo.setText(mResult);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Android `Dialog` for this:

1. Use `CardBuilder` to create the "Completed" card using the `MENU` layout.
2. Create a new instance of `Dialog` and set its content view to be the view returned by `CardBuilder.getView`.
3. Show the dialog.
4. Use `Handler.postDelayed` (or some similar mechanism) to automatically dismiss the dialog after the desired amount of time has passed.

Comment: I don't really follow your advise. Can you please show me some sample code?